# Microsoft Test Manager 2013 automatic tests

Tags: visual-studio-2013, microsoft-test-manager

I’m using TFS2013 with Visual Studio 2013.
I’d like to use Microsoft Test Manager 2013 (MDM) to make a plan.
When I create a plan, I want two different kinds of suites. One is for the manual tests, and the other is for the automatic tests. These last ones are from test cases work items linked to units tests in Visual Studio.
What I’d like to know is can the automatic tests get the results from the build log file built before hand? Or must I have to create an environment and make it execute those tests?

Thank you,
W.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with " get the results from the build log file built before hand"? Which kind of results are you talking about?

Comment: In the build, I run several functional tests. What I'd like is to see the result of those tests in the plan. With a Query suite. I can list the Work Items associated with these tests. But is it possible to see the result of those test within a Plan ?

Comment: How are you starting these functional tests in the build? Are these tests Unit Test running after the build on the build machine?

Comment: Yes, these are in the Unit tests after the build. I don't know where it stores the results of these tests. In the build log, there's a '1 test run completed' entry, with a link that opens the 'Test Results' window in Visual Studio. It shows a list of all the tests, Failed or Passed. I'd like to show these results in the Plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't show the results of *Unit Test* running after the build in *Test Plan* in *Microsoft Test Manager* because there is no connection between these *Unit Tests* and the *Test Plan*.
Using these *Unit Tests* for automation of *Test Cases* that belong to *Test Plan* is not sufficient.

In order to achieve what you want you have to start tests using *tcm.exe*.
This MSDN article may be very helpful for you: [Using tcm to import and run automated tests for a test plan from the command line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff942470.aspx)

This is the "usual" way to use a *Test Plan*.
But if you use it this way you have to create an environment to run the tests on it.

In your case you don't need an extra environment, though, since your tests could apparently be executed on the build machine.
If you want to stick to your approach, please check this article: [How to execute tests locally using TCM.exe command-line?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/12/09/how-to-execute-tests-locally-using-tcm-exe-command-line.aspx)
I've never tried it myself but it sounds like it will do what you want.

If you are going to use "Microsoft Test Manager" in the future I would highly recommend you this **free** e-book: [Testing for Continuous Delivery with Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35380)
This book will be helpful when you are using VS 2013, too, since the approach is similar.